# Windows DNS Change IPv4 vs IPv6

Tags: windows, networking, dns, ipv6

I want to change my DNS settings in Windows and I want to use the Google DNS Servers.

In all tutorials (Microsoft or Google) I read change IPv4 **OR** IPv6..

What does it mean? If I change only IPv6 then I'm automatically on Google DNS or do I have to change both or only IPv4?

[image]

Comment: Are you using IPv6 at all? You want to change the DNS settings for the protocol suite you're using.

Comment: How could I check, which protocol my machine is using?

Answer (score 0):

You can change both, for IPv4 and for IPv6. Using IPv6-DNS-Resolvers is only useful when your connection is IPv6/Dualstack. Otherwise you risk slow DNS-answers.
On IPv6-only connections IPv4-Resolvers are useless.

8.8.8.8

2001:4860:4860::8888

8.8.4.4

2001:4860:4860::8844